# put the headers in italic format

Tags: header-footer, italic

i am  trying to change my headers and footers. i am using this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\leftmark} 
    \fancyhead[RO]{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\thepage} 
    \fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\rightmark} 
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{} 
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{} 
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ -\ #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ -\ #1}{}}
```

where from i got this:

[image]

But I want the header (Chapter 4-Tetracoordinate Iron Carbenes) to be italic.

how cand i do so?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably a `\itshape` right before `\leftmark` or `\rightmark`.

Comment: it not worked ...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `\small` or  `\footnotesize` for the fontsize (depending on the font size option in your document class)?

Here's a possible code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ –\ #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ –\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}
  \setcounter{chapter}{3}

\chapter{Tetracoordinate Iron Carbenes}
\newpage
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section {The reference system}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i am no expert at all. if you could please rewrite how it would be...

Comment: Could you post a full minimal code, please?

Comment: Minimal, but *full, compilable*… Please add it to your initial post, not as a comment.

Comment: my comend below

Comment: `\nouppercase` is a macro with argument; using `\nouppercase\leftmark` works, but it won't with more than one token, so it's better to use `\nouppercase{\leftmark}`. Note also that `\itshape` does `\selectfont`, so the explicit `\selectfont` is redundant.

Comment: it did work bernard. thak you so much!

Comment: What's `\expandafter` for?

Comment: @egreg: I couldn't obtain italic without it, so I tried just in case, and it worked. I don't really know the internals of `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @Bernard Just put `\itshape` in the right spot.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. I thought `\nouppercase` would take the whole following block. Thanks for your suggestion! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's preferable to use higher level commands such as `\footnotesize` rather than `\fontsize`.

Note also that `\nouppercase` is a command taking an argument, so the proper syntax would be `\nouppercase{\itshape\leftmark}`, but the `\itshape` declaration is better made outside `\leftmark`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for testing

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % as requested by fancyhdf

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ -\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ -\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Tetracoordinate Iron Carbenes}

\section{Some title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

If you use a smaller size than 12pt as a document class option, comment out the `\setlength` line and check in the log file for the proper length to assign to `\headheight`.

Actually, since you redefine `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`, `\nouppercase` wouldn't be needed; however, `\tableofcontents` issues `\MakeUppercase` (and, likewise, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`), so it's better to add it anyway.

[image]

Comment: thaks egreg. i got some tips from the code you proposed. but the bernard one is simpler and perfectly worked for what was needing. thak you so much though.

Comment: @ÉgilSá Simpler? I don't think so. It has several redundant bits and fails to show the necessity of setting `\headheight`. If you prefer explicit `\fontsize` declarations, use them (I can't recommend them, though).

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without fancyhdr. You can redefine:

```
\ps@headings
```

Just replace \MakeUppercase by \itshape. (I did this with xparse, this is not necessary, you can just copy the definition from book.cls and replace \MakeUppercase as described.

The same with \tableofcontents.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\DeclareDocumentCommand\ps@headings{}%
 {\let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty%
  \DeclareDocumentCommand\@evenhead{}{\thepage\hfil\leftmark}%
  \DeclareDocumentCommand\@oddhead{}{{\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth%
  \DeclareDocumentCommand\chaptermark{m}%
     {\markboth{\itshape% !!!!
            {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
             \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
           \fi%
           ##1}}{}}%
  \DeclareDocumentCommand\sectionmark{m}%
     {\markright{\itshape% !!!!
               {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@%
              \thesection. \ %
            \fi%
            ##1}}}}

\pagestyle{headings}% Important to load the changes

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \itshape\contentsname}{\itshape\contentsname}}% !!!!
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]